# How to move object around in a smoot motion by calling javascript functions

Tags: javascript, webgl, aframe

I want to be able to move an object from {x= 0, y= 0, z= 0} to {x= 5, y= 0, z= 0} to {x= 5, y= 5, z= 0} for example (by calling functions like changeX(5) in my script). I have tried this by making a javascript loop with setInterval (and a few other methods). But setInterval is a non-blocking function so when i do this for example:

```
changeX(5);

changeY(5);
```

,my object moves from {x= 0, y= 0, z= 0} to {x= 5, y= 5, z= 0} without passing by {x= 5, y= 0, z= 0}.
changeX(n) adjusts a variable xCo to (xCo + n) and I have a loop:

```
function render() {
    sphere.setAttribute('position', coords());
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
function coords() {
    return `${xCo} ${yCo} ${zCo}`;
}
```

which places the object on the right coördinates.

So is there a way i can solve this/ is there a way to add A-frame animation at runtime and would that solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the most common animation technique, the keyframe animation, with linear interpolation.

```
let keyframe = new Array();
// Keyframe components: Time and X,Y,Z coordinates for that time
keyframe.push({t:0.0,x:0,y:0,z:0});
keyframe.push({t:1.5,x:5,y:5,z:0});
keyframe.push({t:2.4,x:3,y:0,z:1});
```

the interpolation function:

```
function getInterpolation(out, time) {

  // select proper segment
  let j = 1;
  while(time >= keyframe[j].t && j < (keyframe.length-1)) j++;
  let i = (j - 1) % keyframe.length;

  // Time phase 0 to 1 between keyframes
  let T = (time - keyframe[i].t) / (keyframe[j].t - keyframe[i].t);

  // linear interpolation
  out.x = keyframe[i].x + T * (keyframe[j].x - keyframe[i].x);
  out.y = keyframe[i].y + T * (keyframe[j].y - keyframe[i].y);
  out.z = keyframe[i].z + T * (keyframe[j].z - keyframe[i].z);
}
```

The way to use this:

```
let time = 0.0;
let coords = {x:0,y:0,z:0};

function render() {

  time += 0.016667; // fake clock

  getInterpolation(coords, time);

  sphere.setAttribute('position', coords);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

You have the rough idea on how that work, you can optimize some parts, make it more modulare, you also can implement a real timer, add a loop process. You also can use other interpolation than the linear one, but this would be another (more mathematical) subject.